# Laravel Signed Route Wierd Behaviour on Heroku depending on the browser

Tags: laravel, apache, heroku, configuration, signed-url

Good day. I have my laravel 8 project hosted on Heroku and it uses signed urls to log the users into the app. The signed URL is created using https:// but it only works on Firefox. It fails to work on Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Also, on clicking the signed URL in the email inbox, it opens a new tab and displays an invalid signature error but on hitting the "Enter" key when the address bar is focused,  the validation is successful and the user is logged in.

For the Heroku Procfile, it is configured as:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Also, I used

```
$request->hasValidSignature();
```

to check the validity of the request.

I have configured the TrustProxies file as:

```
protected $proxies = '*';
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Because Heroku continously cleared internal storage.